# @Onclick android annotations?

Tags: android, android-studio

It appears that android studio supports some additional **annotations** for example `@OnClick` but I am unable to find any documentation on it.

Does anyone know where I can find such documentation. I found something over at the tools website but it didn't include `@OnClick`.

Anyone know what this **annotation** does?

Thanks

Comment: I've just looked inside the support annotations jar and it doesn't have a OnClick annotation. Are you sure that annotation doesn't come from other libraries(like ButterKnife for example) added to your project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes . I think that is **Butter Knife** injection annotation for `onClick`

see this link for [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

example code for `onClick`

```
@OnClick(R.id.submit)
public void sayHi(Button button) {
  button.setText("Hello!");
}
```